# Unable to read contact sort order in iOS (address book API seems broken)

Tags: iphone, ios4, addressbook

I'm trying to use `ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat()` to read the sort order settings for the user's address book. It always returns `kABPersonCompositeNameFormatFirstNameFirst` regardless of how I configure the "Display Order" preference in the Settings application. The Address Book application changes appropriately when the display order is set to "Last First" but the API call always returns the same value that represents the "First Last" display order. Has anybody else had this problem? I'm running this on an iPhone4 with iOS 4.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

I've just found a solution - ABAddressBookRef has to be obtained (by ABAddressBookCreate) at least once before calling to ABPersonGetCompositeNameFormat(), but there are no mentions about it in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
        people = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByLastName);
```

It helps you.